# How do I get my TwoSum method to work with numbers that aren't in order?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm currently working on a LeetCode question called TwoSums.

It requires me to:

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

My code works with different lengths of arrays. However, I found that when the numbers aren't in order, it gives the wrong answers.

My test case was [3,2,4] Target number = 6.

```
public class Solution {
       
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) 
    {        
        int[] ret = new int[2]; 
        int start = 0
        int end = nums.Length - 1;
    
        while(start < end)
        {
           if (nums[start] + nums[end] == target)
           {
              ret[0] = start; 
              ret[1] = end;
              break; 
           }
           else if(nums[start] + nums[end] < target)
           {
              start++;
           }
           else
           {
              end--; 
           }
       }return(ret); 
   }    
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm assumes that `nums` is sorted. The whole "if the sum is too small then increase the first number: if it's too large then decrease the second number" thing relies on the input being sorted in ascending order. Either you need to sort the input yourself (and map the indexes in your sorted array back to indexes in the unsorted array), or your algorithm needs to change.

Comment: @canton7 could you recommend an algorithm that I could look in to? I'm pretty new at this, so I'm not so sure where to begin.

Comment: If the input can be in any order, and you don't want to sort it, you'll have to try adding every pair of numbers in the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a trivial brute-force solution which checks every pair of numbers. This has time complexity O(n^2):

```
public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.Length; j++)
        {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
            {
                return new[] { i, j };  
            }
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Solution not found");
}
```

We take care not to try any pair more than once - `j` always starts above `i`.

Comment: hehe same thought

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 nested loops. :

```
public static int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    int[] ret = new int[2]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.Length; j++)
        {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
            {
                ret[0] = i; 
                ret[1] = j;
                return ret;
            }
        }   
    }
    return null; // This avoid compiler to complain about "not all path returns a value"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation assumes the list is sorted, because in the second if you check if the sum of `start` and `end` is smaller than `target`. Try this approach:

```
public class Solution
{
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        int[] ret = new int[2]; 

        if (nums.Length < 2)
            return ret;

        int start = 0;
        int end = 1;

        while (start < (nums.Length -1))
        {           
            if (nums[start] + nums[end] == target)
            {
                ret[0] = start; 
                ret[1] = end;
                break; 
            }

            if (end < nums.Length -1))
            {
                end++
            }
            else
            {
                start++;
                end = start + 1
            }
        }

        return ret; 
    }

}
```

It starts with `start` looking at index `0` and `end` at the next element. If it matches the target it returns the result. If not, it increments `end` until it reaches the end of the array. Than it wil increment `start` and reset `end` to `start + 1`, to look at the next element again. And so on until `start` reaches the last element. It then has checked all combinations.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to approach this but the most direct - as already pointed out by the other answers - is nested loops.

What they all missed, including myself until I read your question again, was this:

> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution,

While it seems unimportant, this actually gives us a small optimization: reverse the search.

Using the forward method for your given inputs there are 3 comparisons done to find the answer:

```
[0, 1] => 3 + 2 != 6
[0, 2] => 3 + 4 != 6
[1, 2] => 2 + 4 == 6
```

For each pass through the outer loop the number of passes through the inner loop decreases.  Unless the answer includes the first item in the array that means that you're testing more than you need to.

If we reverse the search we eliminate pairs from each outer loop faster:

```
static int[] TwoSums(int target, int[] array)
{
    for (int i1 = array.Length - 2; i1 >= 0; i1--)
    {
        int v1 = array[i1];
        for (int i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < array.Length; i2++)
        {
            if (v1 + array[i2] == target)
                return new[] { i1, i2 };
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This way the sequence for your example is:

```
[1, 2] => 2 + 4 == 6
```

That's a little bit of a cheat though, since the answer in this case is the last pair.  Let's try something different and compare:

```
Array: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31]
Test value: 24
```

With a little instrumentation we can see how many times we run through the loop.  For this particular case the forward search does 22 comparisons before it finds the one that works while the reverse does only 11.  If the test value were 48 (19 + 29) the numbers would be: Forward=49, Reverse=5.

Of course if the answer includes one of the first couple of values then the numbers flip.  It's a game of averages.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] indexes = GetSumIndexes(new int[] { 3, 2, 4 }, 6);
    }

    public static int[] GetSumIndexes(int[] numbers, int target)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                if (i != j)
                {
                    if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target)
                    {
                        return new int[] { i, j };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new int[] { };
    }
}
```

Output:

> [1,2]

---

Optimized version you can find in the other answers:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] indexes = GetSumIndexes(new int[] { 3, 2, 4 }, 6);
    }

    public static int[] GetSumIndexes(int[] numbers, int target)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target)
                {
                    return new int[] { i, j };
                }
            }
        }
        return new int[] { };
    }
}
```

Output:

> [1,2]

Comment: You can be smarter about where `j` starts (and where `i` finishes), and drastically reduce the number of loops. Yours will compare e.g. both `3 + 2` and `2 + 3`. See the other answers to this question.

Comment: @canton7 but their implementation doesn't cover every scenario

Comment: What do you mean by "every scenario"? Addition is commutative - `3 + 2` always gives the same answer as as `2 + 3`.

Comment: You're right it does, anyway downvoting is wrong, this answer isn't wrong, just not optimized